# How can I connect ubuntu 19.10 to a projector?

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 desktop on a asus laptop with Ubuntu DE. My laptop doesn't have a VGA port to connect to a projector directly thus I should get it to connect through HDMI to VGA converter. In the older version of Ubuntu like 14.04 we could use Display settings to connect Ubuntu to projector. As you can see in the below I haven't any option to use to get it to connect to the projector.
[image]

How can I get it to work? Thanks

Comment: Got it working once I plugged in HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it to work by connecting HDMI-to-VGA converter to the projector and all options in the Display Settings appeared successfully.

Comment: Yes. Second-display (including projector) for most folks is automatic. Simply plug it in and see what happens. Options are indeed hidden until after detection.